# So how do I make a class name global in PHP?

Tags: php, class, scope

I have a class called "user" with a function "createAccount". Within it I like to access another class via PostageApp::mail

But as this class is outside the scope it is not accessible. `global` seams to work for variables only. So how do I make a class name global?

```
include_once('../../ext_scripts/postageapp_class.inc');

class user {
  function createAccount(...) {
    global PostageApp;

    [...]

    $result = PostageApp::mail($mailTo, '', 'verify_email', array());
  }
}
```

Comment: Class identifiers are global by default. Except if one of your two lives in a namespace.

Comment: Thanks, I just found out, that the include path was wrong. And thats why PostageApp was not know.

Comment: I recommend you use `require` instead of `include` for mandatory source files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure that the class has been defined in an included file, there is only one thing affecting its visibility in another file: I suppose the `PostageApp` class is in another [namespace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php), as this is the only reason another class could have a different scope in PHP.

The keyword [`global`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) is only necessary for global variables. Functions and classes are always accessible in any scope as soon as they have been declared.

Answer (score 3):

The class have to be defined before you use it, so you have use [`require`](http://fr.php.net/require) or [`require_once`](http://fr.php.net/require_once) to include the file with your `PostageApp` class definition.

There is no notion of global for classes.

If you don't want to add the `require`, I advise you to look into [autoloading](http://fr.php.net/manual/fr/function.spl-autoload.php).